# how to merge words in php array

Tags: php, arrays

hi i have an array after doing explodes and other stuff in a following format.

```
[556] => Thorold
[557] => $130
[558] => Tilbury
[559] => $420
[560] => Tillsongbury
[561] => $225

[570] => Toronto
[571] => (Danforth
[572] => Area)
[573] => $55
[574] => Toronto
[575] => (Davisville
[576] => Area)
[577] => $50
[578] => Toronto
[579] => (Downtown
[580] => Area)
[581] => $50
[582] => Toronto
[583] => (East
[584] => York
[585] => Area)
[586] => $60
```

i want to group the words in a single index and the price in the next one i.e.
$data[0] = Toronto ( Downtown Area)
$data[1] = $50.00

please suggest or help out.

Comment: May be you should handle this problem while doing explode

Comment: Maybe you should not use `explode` then. What is the original data and what do you want to get as result?

Comment: Why having different data in the same array? Why not $data[0]['area'] and $data[0]['price']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?
$source_array = array( 'A', 'B', '$50', 'C', 'D', 'E', '$200');
var_dump($source_array);

$portion = '';
$temp = array();
$result = array(array_pop($source_array));
while($item = array_pop($source_array)) {
   if(substr($item, 0, 1) == '$') {
     array_unshift($result, $item, implode($temp, ' '));
     $temp = array();
     $portion = '';
   } else {
     array_unshift($temp, $item);
   }
}

array_unshift($result, implode($temp, ' '));
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Amazing Solution the only problem is some of the data is like. string(9) "Beeton$90"
  [25]=>
  string(13) "Bellville$275" 
  [26]=>
  string(14) "BelleRiver$499"
  [27]=>
  string(9) "Beeton$95"
  [28]=>
  string(14) "Blackstock$140"
  [29]=>
  string(17) "BlueMountains$225"
 and i want  Blue Mountains with a space and then in the next index the price.

Comment: you are champion , can u share your mind with me so that i use bit of your brain when programming. i wish to donote you. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If your string is like this (which it seems to be)

```
$str = "Toronto (Danforth Area) $55 Toronto (Davisville Area) $50";
```

and the city names (or part of them) never end with a number, you can use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) to get the desired structure:

```
preg_split('/\s+(?=\$)|(?<=\d)\s+/', $str);
```

gives

```
Array
(
    [0] => Toronto (Danforth Area)
    [1] => $55
    [2] => Toronto (Davisville Area)
    [3] => $50
)
```

Comment: Applying regex on a single string permits a much more concise method than iterating an input array.  Good answer.  I posted something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
$newArray = array();
for ($i = 0, $max = count($oldArray); $i < $max; $i++) {
    $key = '';
    while (substr($oldArray[$i], 0, 1) <> '$') {
        $key .= ' ' . $oldArray[$i];
        $i++;
    }
    $newArray[trim($key)] = $oldArray[$i];
}
```

Comment: This is taking too long to finish can you please simply the code cuz after this i am going to do other operations on the code this is not going to run on the client this all to extract the data

Answer (score 0):

I must say I agree with Felix's thinking, and that is probably the method (or similar) that I would be using if this was my project.

However, in the absence of seeing what explosions and other actions you are performing to prepare your data, this is what I would suggest:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ZMrvU))

```
$location = '';
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $v) {
    if (substr($v, 0, 1) != '$') {
        $location .= ($location ? ' ' : '') . $v;  // concatenate
    } else {
        array_push($result, $location, $v);  // store location then dollar amount
        // or make associative... $result[$location] => $v;
        $location = '';  // restart
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'Thorold',
  1 => '$130',
  2 => 'Tilbury',
  3 => '$420',
  4 => 'Tillsongbury',
  5 => '$225',
  6 => 'Toronto (Danforth Area)',
  7 => '$55',
  8 => 'Toronto (Davisville Area)',
  9 => '$50',
  10 => 'Toronto (Downtown Area)',
  11 => '$50',
  12 => 'Toronto (East York Area)',
  13 => '$60',
)
```

---

Here is my version of a regex method: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/A5fUC))

```
$string = 'Thorold $130 Tilbury $420 Tillsongbury $225 Toronto (Danforth Area) $55 Toronto (Davisville Area) $50 Toronto (Downtown Area) $50 Toronto (East York Area) $60';

var_export(preg_split('/ ?(\$\d+) ?/', $string, 0, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
// same output as my above non-regex method
```

This uses a simpler pattern and leverages the function's flags to ensure that the dollar amount is not omitted and that no empty elements are produced.